# Add Objects from one ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 9 `ArrayList`s and I'm trying to condense them all down into one at a given point.

at the moment `dotGrid` is a matrix of `ArrayList`s, `searchX` and `searchY` simply specify which `ArrayList`s to add to `neighbours`.

```
for(int searchX = sector[0] - 1; searchX < sector[0] + 2; searchX++){
  for(int searchY = sector[1] - 1; searchY < sector[1] + 2; searchY++){
    if(searchX >= 0 && searchX < 16 && searchY >= 0 && searchY < 16){
      neighbours.add(dotGrid[searchX][searchY]);
    }
  }
}
```

from what I understand `neighbours.addAll()` should work, but it isn't.

I really have been searching quite hard, but haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer.

thanks in advance

Comment: "neighbours.addAll() should work, but it isn't." What is not working? Does it give an error? Or yield strange results?

Comment: A more complete code example would be useful (pastebin), noteably the declarations for dotGrid and neigbours. Also, you're not using neighbours.addAll there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> ```
> neighbours.add(dotGrid[searchX][searchY])
> ```

`dotGrid` is an array.  Typically, you can't instantiate an array of a fully qualified generic type:

```
List<Double>[][] dotGrid = new List<Double>[n][];
```

will fail with a type error, so I'm going to assume that `dotGrid` is partially typed?

```
List[][] dotGrid;
```

which means that `addAll(dotGrid[searchX][searchY])` will fail because you are trying to add all elements of a `List` to a `List<Double>`.

Ideally, you wouldn't mix object arrays with generic lists, and instead redefine `dotGrid` to be a list of lists of lists:

```
List<List<List<Double>>> dotGrid;
```

If that won't work, you can try to `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` to make sure that `dotGrid` has a fully qualified type after instantiation, or do something like the following

```
@SuppressWarning("unchecked")
List<Double> cell = (List<Double>) dotGrid[searchX][searchY];
neighbours.addAll(cell);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `List#add` method expects an element which can be added to the `List`. So if your `dotGrid` is a 'matrix of `ArrayList`s', you try to add an `ArrayList` to your `List` instead of adding all elements of that `List`. You should use the `addAll` method instead as you mentioned in your answer, but in your code you use the regular `add` method

```
neighbours.addAll(dotGrid[searchX][searchY]);
```

The following code works just fine, illustrating the usage of the `addAll` method

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList( 0, 1 ) );
List<Integer> anotherList = new ArrayList<Integer>(  );
anotherList.addAll( list );
```